# Authenticate Game Center problem : "Cannot call value of non-function type UIViewController"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

При подключении к game center получаю ошибку:

> "Cannot call value of non-function type UIViewController"

Вот это мой код :

```
func authenticateLocalPlayer(){
    let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(ViewController , error) -> Void in
        if ViewController != nil{
            self.presentedViewController(ViewController , animated: true , completion : nil)
        }else {
            print("Authentification is \(GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ну если вкратце, то вам надо вместо `ViewController` писать `viewController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так

```
func authenticateLocalPlayer() {
    let localPlayer = GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer()
    localPlayer.authenticateHandler = {(viewController , error) -> Void in
        if viewController != nil{
            self.presentViewController(viewController! , animated: true , completion : nil)
        }else {
            print("Authentification is \(GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Max Mikheyenko Вссе получилось

Comment: ну ставьте галочку :)

Comment: Ставил ) , я только щас понял что этого есть )) , хорошо что сказали надо щас вернуться остальными галочки ставить )